# WinRT - UI virtualization loading images async blocking UI Thread

Tags: c#, image, winrt-xaml, virtualization, winrt-async

I'm having problems with my image loading blocking the UI thread so my gridview is not responsive in my windows store app.

What I'm trying to do is for the images in gridview to have a binding to image property in my view model. The value of image property is set by an async method. When app starts it loads all objects, but not the actual image data. The image data is loaded when the UI virtualization kicks in and requestes the image data via the image property bound to the image control in xaml.

All this is done in an observablecollection.

Here is some code:

```
    private ImageSource _image = null;
    private String _imagePath = null;
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get
        {
            SetImageFromStorageFile().ContinueWith(OnAsyncFail, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
            return this._image;
        }
    }

    private async Task SetImageFromStorageFile()
    {
        this.IsLoading = true;
        if (this._image == null && this._imagePath != null)
        {
                this._image = await BitmapLoader.GetPreviewImageFromStorageFile(this.StorageFile); //getting the actual data here
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Image");
        }
        this.IsLoading = false;
    }
```

This is all working fine except that the UI becomes unresponsive when accessing the image data.

As you can see I'm calling an async method from a property, I'm just reusing the code that I call from other places. When called from other places I can use await and the UI is responsive. The problem is that when using the gridviews UI virtualization I don't know how to run this async method without blocking the UI since properties are not possible to run async (as far as I know).

So I just want the gridview to run this property (or method) async instead of sync, but don't know how to do it.

Please help :)

Comment: After tearing my hair off with this I decided to see if the grid was the problem. And if I removed using the grouping and just used a plain grid it worked as I expected. So I don't really have an answer to my question, but a workaround. Not nice though.

Answer (score 1):

```
private ImageSource _image = null;
private String _imagePath = null;
public ImageSource Image
{
    get
    {
        if (_image != null)
          return _image;
        if (_imagePath != null && !IsLoading)
          SetImageFromStorageFile();
        return null;
    }
}

private async void SetImageFromStorageFile()
{
    if (this.IsLoading || this._image != null || this._imagePath == null)
      return;
    this.IsLoading = true;
    try
    {
      this._image = await BitmapLoader.GetPreviewImageFromStorageFile(this.StorageFile); //getting the actual data here
      this.IsLoading = false;
      this.OnPropertyChanged("Image");
    }
    catch 
    {
      OnAsyncFail();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you change your signature to VOID instead of TASK.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever strategy you choose, you need to return something first and fill it later. This is a sample which has been tested in a vanilla WinRT page; you can duplicate it by dropping it onto a page with an `Image` named `image` and a `TextBlock` named `status`. This can go in `OnNavigatedTo`, or another appropriate place.

```
BitmapImage imgsrc = new BitmapImage();
Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler(() =>
                {
                    imgsrc.UriSource = new Uri("http://www.gratuit-en-ligne.com/telecharger-gratuit-en-ligne/telecharger-image-wallpaper-gratuit/image-wallpaper-animaux/img/images/image-wallpaper-animaux-autruche.jpg");
                }));
    });
image.Source = imgsrc;
status.Text = "Done";
```

The thing I am "returning" is a `BitmapImage`, which is a subclass of `ImageSource`, so it's close to what you will want to use. The `Task.Delay()` is just to introduce obvious lag between startup and image population, so that you can see that the status text is set well before the image is loaded.

To make this work with your sample, you will need to create (or access) an `ImageSource` in your property and return it immediately, without waiting for it to be filled. Then you start off a background task that assigns the actual source data.

The actual chain of causation could be different than what I show here. You could, for instance, access the ImageSources from a pre-created collection of them. This would allow you to start loading the images before the property is ever called. But it sounds like this will be a start to get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunatly this didn't help in my case, but it should have :)